# Check nibName of the previous UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation based app. In a certain screen, I need to check from which screen the user came. I thought about something like

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
int viewControllersSize = [viewControllers count];
if ([[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllersSize-2] nibName] == @"Name") {
    ...
}
```

But the problem is that if the user clicks "back" from a certain screen, the view controller will be removed from the array defined above.

My current solution is having a global variable that tells me if the user came from a specific screen, but I suppose there is a more elegant solution, right?

Comment: Get it working correctly and then worry about elegant.  There is nothing wrong with a global variable if that's what you need.

Comment: It is working correctly with the global variable.

Comment: Then on to the next problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant with:

> But the problem is that if the user
>   clicks "back" from a certain screen,
>   the view controller will be removed
>   from the array defined above.

Not all view controllers use same navigation controller?

If same UINavigationController is used for all UIViewControllers, you can use UIViewController parentViewController for this purpose. If going the opposite way, keeping reference to view controller you came from or maybe just [viewController class] (to string) would do the trick.

Comment: I tried logging "self.parentViewController.nibName" or "self.navigationController.parentViewController.nibName", but they are both null...

Comment: Which way are you allocation nibs? See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName) for more info.

Comment: exampleViewController *e = [[exampleViewController alloc] 
                           initWithNibName:@"ExampleView" 
                           bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.example = e;
        [e release];